# stview from summarytools doesn't show all the variable categories

Tags: r, summarytools

I used this code to get a view onto my data.

```
library(summarytools)
stview(dfSummary(df))
```

Unfortunately, the output doesn't include all the years in the data frame. Is there a way to modify `stview` to show all variable categories, or do I need another method for this?

[image]

Sample of my data

```
structure(list(RUUMIS = c("Torso", "Torso", "Head", "Leg", "Leg", 
"Leg", "Arm", "Head", "Torso", "Torso", "Head", "Arm", "Leg", 
"Torso", "Head", "Arm", "Head", "Head", "Torso", "Head", "Torso", 
"Head", "Leg", "Head", "Torso", "Leg", "Head", "Arm", "Leg", 
"Leg", "Torso", "Torso", "Leg", "Torso", "Head", "Arm", "Head", 
"Arm", "Torso", "Arm", "Arm", "Head", "Head", "Torso", "Head", 
"Arm", "Leg", "Leg", "Leg", "Head", "Arm", "Head", "Arm", "Arm", 
"Torso", "Head", "Torso", "Head", "Head", "Arm", "Torso", "Leg", 
"Leg", "Arm", "Head", "Torso", "Torso", "Arm", "Arm", "Torso", 
"Arm", "Torso", "Torso", "Arm", "Head", "Head", "Leg", "Leg", 
"Torso", "Arm", "Torso", "Head", "Arm", "Arm", "Arm", "Torso", 
"Head", "Leg", "Head", "Leg", "Arm", "Head", "Arm", "Arm", "Arm", 
"Arm", "Leg", "Head", "Head", "Torso"), YEAR = structure(c(16L, 
6L, 9L, 15L, 7L, 3L, 19L, 12L, 5L, 14L, 6L, 5L, 8L, 11L, 11L, 
19L, 7L, 7L, 14L, 5L, 12L, 14L, 5L, 9L, 5L, 7L, 3L, 5L, 18L, 
19L, 5L, 5L, 9L, 11L, 16L, 1L, 13L, 3L, 10L, 1L, 17L, 2L, 8L, 
17L, 7L, 13L, 16L, 1L, 13L, 10L, 7L, 6L, 5L, 8L, 3L, 3L, 16L, 
5L, 11L, 12L, 15L, 3L, 4L, 17L, 16L, 2L, 16L, 1L, 11L, 5L, 15L, 
18L, 7L, 12L, 9L, 18L, 3L, 2L, 18L, 15L, 13L, 18L, 10L, 6L, 14L, 
7L, 11L, 6L, 15L, 6L, 16L, 5L, 7L, 14L, 2L, 13L, 2L, 13L, 7L, 
19L), levels = c("2003", "2004", "2005", "2006", "2007", "2008", 
"2009", "2010", "2011", "2012", "2013", "2014", "2015", "2016", 
"2017", "2018", "2019", "2020", "2021"), class = "factor")), row.names = c(581L, 
118L, 322L, 281L, 423L, 912L, 201L, 570L, 788L, 249L, 405L, 448L, 
49L, 484L, 33L, 270L, 173L, 14L, 429L, 686L, 498L, 34L, 564L, 
533L, 792L, 622L, 949L, 32L, 950L, 50L, 902L, 891L, 961L, 935L, 
553L, 762L, 664L, 211L, 658L, 866L, 567L, 587L, 804L, 667L, 843L, 
232L, 264L, 328L, 685L, 175L, 738L, 793L, 962L, 851L, 953L, 95L, 
602L, 795L, 195L, 789L, 171L, 363L, 730L, 803L, 432L, 243L, 442L, 
528L, 927L, 129L, 109L, 177L, 627L, 737L, 836L, 418L, 480L, 62L, 
294L, 58L, 456L, 696L, 626L, 906L, 928L, 53L, 153L, 167L, 510L, 
285L, 78L, 158L, 865L, 736L, 331L, 741L, 879L, 684L, 247L, 637L
), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: `stview(dfSummary(df, max.distinct.values = 100))`?  A number of formatting options can be found using `?dfSummary`